# Prove that integral of infinite sum is in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The function $g$ is a composition of functions as follows ($\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of the set $A$):

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \chi_{[0,1]}(x)$$

For an enumeration of the rationals $\{r_i\}$:
$$g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}f(x-r_n)$$

Prove that $g \in L^1(m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure for $m$ almost everywhere on $x$. Prove that $g$ is unbounded on every open interval $I \in [0,1]$ and that $\forall I, \forall N \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow m(\{x\in I : g(x)>N\}) > 0$

Putting everything in place, we have

$$\int \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\frac{\chi_{[0,1](x-r_n)}}{\sqrt{x-r_n}} dm$$

Analyzing the parts of this function, we see that $2^{-n} \geq 0; \chi \geq 0$ I don't know how to show that with the denominator this is a function in $L^+$. I know that for being in $L^1$ I am interested in $|f|$ but I am still unsure if I should and how to proceed about this.

If I could show that, then we can swap the sum and the integral and get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int 2^{-n}\frac{\chi_{[0,1](x-r_n)}}{\sqrt{x-r_n}} dm$$

where

$$\int 2^{-n}\frac{\chi_{[0,1](x-r_n)}}{\sqrt{x-r_n}} dm \leq \int 2^{-n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-r_n}} dm \leq \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-r_n}}dm$$

Do I proceed with some sort of limit theorem or keep trying to prove that this is less than some other function?

Comment: Do you know Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monotone convergence theorem (@GNU, @zhw in the comments) with translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure implies that
$$
\int_\Bbb R \sum_{n\ge 1}2^{-n}f(x-r_n)\mathrm dm = \sum_{n\ge 1}2^{-n} \int_\Bbb Rf(x-r_n)\mathrm dm =\sum_{n\ge 1}2^{-n} \int_\Bbb R f=\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x}}=2.
$$ So, $g\ge 0$ is in $L^1(\Bbb R,m)$. To see that $g$ is unbounded on any $I$ and $m\{x\in I:g(x)>N\}>0$ for all $N$, note that there is $r_k\in I$ for some $k$. Also note that since $I$ is open, we can choose $\delta$ so that $(r_k,r_k+\delta)\subset I$ and at the same time $\delta<\min\{\frac1{4^kN^2},1\}$. If $x\in (r_k,r_k+\delta)$, then we have
$$
g(x)\ge 2^{-k}f(x-r_k)=2^{-k}\frac1{\sqrt{x-r_k}}\ge  2^{-k}\frac1{\sqrt\delta}>2^{-k}\cdot 2^kN =N.
$$ We can see that
$$m\{x\in I:g(x)>N\}\ge m(r_k,r_k+\delta)=\delta>0$$ and since $N$ is arbitrary, $g(x)$ is unbounded as $x\xrightarrow{} r_k^+$.

Comment: Doesn't $\delta $ (satisfying $(r_k,r_k+\delta) \subset I$) depend in $k$. I doubt if we have any control over $2^{-k}\frac 1 {\sqrt \delta}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Umm ... I see it this way. Since $I$ is open, there is $\delta_k>0$ such that for all $\delta\in (0,\delta_k)$, it holds $(r_k,r_k+\delta)\subset I$. $\delta_k>0$ depends on $k$, but essentially, large $\delta\ge \delta_k$ is not really necessary in the argument. Is it convincing ..?

Comment: How do you show that $f \in L^+$? I thought the denominator could be complex

Comment: @TheBosco How does that happen when $f(x-r_n)$ is just translation of $f(x)$?

Comment: Nevermind, it was because of the denominator that I was having trouble seeing it. But I didn't take into account that $f$ would be $0$ because of the $\chi$ function.

Comment: At the end of your equation, how do you come to the conclusion of the last equality?

Comment: I meant $\sum 2^{-n} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: @TheBosco  Because $\sum_{n\ge 1}2^{-n} \cdot \int_{\Bbb R} f = \int_\mathbb{R} f = \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{x}|^1_0=2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89772/discussion-between-the-bosco-and-song).

Comment: @Song Sorry, I was a bit confused. Your proof is fine.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No, no it's okay! Thereafter, I've edited it since it was indeed written quite unclearly.

Comment: Fubini Tonelli not needed; it's just the MCT.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks! I have edited. I felt it was too much but went on anyway ...