# Integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ essentially unbonded on any ball

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

For any integer $d\ge 1$, I would like to find a function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that for any ball $B\in \mathbb{R}^d$, $f$ is not essentially bounded on $B$.

If you solely asks that $f$ be essentially unbounded on any ball containing a point, the origin, for example, then the function $|x|^{-d+\varepsilon}\chi_{|x|\le 1}$ for $0<\varepsilon<1$ is integrable but unbounded on any such ball. However, I'm not sure how to come up with a function that is essentially unbounded on any ball.

Comment: Enumerate all rational points in $\mathbb R^d$ as $q_n$ and then sum $f(x-q_n)2^{-n}$ where $f$ is your function

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. If you write that as an answer, I will approve it.

Comment: Its OK, I don't need the rep and I found this related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3113769/prove-that-integral-of-infinite-sum-is-in-l1 :)